# Pass old input after Form Request validation in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

if the validation fails it's not clear to me how i could pass the old input to fill again the form.

I mean, I know how to pass the data when using the Validator class and redirecting after fail with the method withInput(), but I'm trying to learn how to use Form Requests provided in laravel 5. Thanks

Comment: The form requests [do that for you automatically](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L94).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
$username = Request::old('username');
```

or in view:

```
{{ old('username') }}
```

Read more: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#old-input

Comment: {{{ old('username') }}} // for laravel earlier versions xss preventing

Comment: I had to use the e() function in this case  <input id=targa type=text name=targa size=10{!! (old('targa'))?' value="'.e(old('targa')).'"':' placeholder="Ej. AAA000"' !!}> do you have any other idea to do the same thing? I will have to do it almost for every field as i love to use placeholders

Comment: @Gabz if you're using L5 you don't need to follow Alupotha comment.

Comment: @Alupotha author mentioned L5 in question and in tag.

Comment: This does not seem to work for file uploads form - I cannot seem to populate the file upload section within a form - it just returns an empty array

Answer (score 8):

You can redirect with old data like below with validation error

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

Comment: i tried this, but not working for me, we just need to pas this in controller right if validation condition fails

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">`

you must also define withInput() for the http route when redirecting to a page for example

`return back()->withInput();`